# How can I ask my manager how to timecharge a work-related "fun" event?

Tags: communication, time-management

I'm an intern at a large company, and they sent an email to all of the interns with free tickets to a baseball game this coming week. The tickets are free of charge, but we have to pay for our own transportation to the game, if necessary. Also in the email, it mentioned that what to do for time-charging should be done on a case-by-case basis.

I would be perfectly fine going to the game without any time charging, just using it as unpaid time off, but if my manager says it's okay to use an overhead number, then obviously I would prefer that.

So how can I word me asking him what to do in a way that makes it clear that I have no expectation to get paid for going to the baseball game?

Comment: Is the baseball game during normal working hours?  If not, to ask about getting paid will make you look stupid IMO.

Comment: The game is during working hours. My plan is to be at work about 8-10, then leave to go to the game.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the email you received *hadn't* mentioned time charging, this would be simple: you just don't ask the question. You've been given something nice, just enjoy it. Personally, I'd still take this approach.

However, as the email did mention time charging, you could send something like this to your boss:

> Hi boss.
>
> Thanks very much to both you and the company for arranging the tickets to the baseball game. The email I received says the time charging is on a "case-by-case basis". My assumption would be that this isn't charged and is unpaid time off, but if I'm wrong, please let me know.
>
> Thanks,
>
> Calvin

Comment: Great answer, but always assume the positive outcome.

"Thanks for the tickets. I'm looking forward to this _team building activity_ and would like to know the charge code.

Sincerely,
Sports Go Sports!"